# Выпадающее меню по всей ширине

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать выпадающее меню длинной по всей ширине? То ест что бы например при нажатии на пункт меню номер 6, выпадающее меню было полностью по всей ширине.

```js
/**
 * BOOTSTRAP DROPDOWN JS
 */

+function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION

    var backdrop = '.dropdown-backdrop'
    var toggle   = '[data-dropdown]'
    var Dropdown = function (element) {
        $(element).on('click.bs.dropdown', this.toggle)
    }

    function getParent($this) {
        var selector = $this.attr('data-target')

        if (!selector) {
            selector = $this.attr('href')
            selector = selector && /#[A-Za-z]/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') // strip for ie7
        }

        var $parent = selector && $(selector)

        return $parent && $parent.length ? $parent : $this.parent()
    }

    function clearMenus(e) {
        if (e && e.which === 3) return
        $(backdrop).remove()
        $(toggle).each(function () {
            var $this         = $(this)
            var $parent       = getParent($this)
            var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this }

            if (!$parent.hasClass('open')) return

            if (e && e.type == 'click' && /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName) && $.contains($parent[0], e.target)) return

            $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('hide.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

            $this.attr('aria-expanded', 'false')
            $parent.removeClass('open').trigger($.Event('hidden.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))
        })
    }

    Dropdown.prototype.toggle = function (e) {
        var $this = $(this)

        if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) bledreturn

        var $parent  = getParent($this)
        var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

        clearMenus()

        if (!isActive) {
            if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement && !$parent.closest('.navbar-nav').length) {
                // if mobile we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
                $(document.createElement('div'))
                    .addClass('dropdown-backdrop')
                    .insertAfter($(this))
                    .on('click', clearMenus)
            }

            var relatedTarget = { relatedTarget: this }
            $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('show.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))

            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

            $this
                .trigger('focus')
                .attr('aria-expanded', 'true')

            $parent
                .toggleClass('open')
                .trigger($.Event('shown.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget))
        }

        return false
    }

    Dropdown.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
        if (!/(38|40|27|32)/.test(e.which) || /input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return

        var $this = $(this)

        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()

        if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return

        var $parent  = getParent($this)
        var isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')

        if (!isActive && e.which != 27 || isActive && e.which == 27) {
            if (e.which == 27) $parent.find(toggle).trigger('focus')
            return $this.trigger('click')
        }

        var desc = ' li:not(.disabled):visible a'
        var $items = $parent.find('.dropdown-block' + desc)

        if (!$items.length) return

        var index = $items.index(e.target)

        if (e.which == 38 && index > 0)                 index--         // up
        if (e.which == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++         // down
        if (!~index)                                    index = 0

        $items.eq(index).trigger('focus')
    }


    // DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
    // ==========================

    function Plugin(option) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            var data  = $this.data('bs.dropdown')

            if (!data) $this.data('bs.dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
            if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
        })
    }

    var old = $.fn.dropdown

    $.fn.dropdown             = Plugin
    $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown


    // DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
    // ====================

    $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
        $.fn.dropdown = old
        return this
    }


    // APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
    // ===================================

    $(document)
        .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
        .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
        .on('click.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
        .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', toggle, Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
        .on('keydown.bs.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-block', Dropdown.prototype.keydown)

}(jQuery);
```

```css
.header-middle .base-nav {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul:after {
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.base-nav-btn {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 12.5%;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.open {
    border-top: 3px solid #e74c3c;
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.base-nav-btn > a {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.base-nav-btn > a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.base-nav-btn > a > .img-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.base-nav-btn > a > .img-container > img {
    height: 35px;
    width: auto;
}
.header-middle .base-nav > ul > li.open > a > .base-subnav {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}


/*=========== BOOTSTRAP DROPDOWN ==============*/
.dropdown-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-middle">
    <div class="hp-container">
      
      <!-- Тут лого поиск и тд -->
      
      <!-- BASE NAV -->
      <section class="base-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="base-nav-btn dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-dropdown>
              <div class="img-container">
                <img src="assets/img/b_nav1.png" alt="image" />
              </div>
              <div class="base-nav-text">Компьютеры</div>
              <div class="dropdown-block base-subnav">
                <ul>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="base-nav-btn dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-dropdown>
              <div class="img-container">
                <img src="assets/img/b_nav2.png" alt="image" />
              </div>
              <div class="base-nav-text">Телефоны и связь</div>
              <div class="dropdown-block base-subnav">
                <ul>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                  <li>asdsa</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <!-- END BASE NAV -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать `position: static;` у родительского `li`